# How to store value in html / jquery

Tags: jquery, html

i need to store few element in temp variable, so when i get back to that pahe i can show them on page load

i have about `8 li element` but let's i click on `5 li`, so i want to store `5 li` id somewhere

```
$("#divPopup").on("click", "li", function () {
            ...
                var newId = $this.attr('Id').replace("Left", "Right")

                // here i want to store newID, each time user click on event, it should be unique values  , i want to store in $('#hdnValueProjectBtn').val(newId);
            }
            else {
                var newId = $this.attr('Id').replace("Left", "Right")
                $('#' + newId).hide();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Use a cookie to store temporary values.

Comment: Cookies or localStorage are what you need.

Comment: Yes, but i dont want to use cookie

Comment: You want to store it while that page is open? if the user come back to the same page would it have the values?

Comment: Luis Tellez, you are right

Answer (score 1):

You can use `localStorage` in supported browsers and fallback to `Cookies` in older ones, here is an example:

```
// store value
if (window.localStorage !== undefined) {
    window.localStorage.setItem("li_id", id);
} else {
    // WARNING: the following will overwrite current document cookie.
    document.cookie = ["li_id", "=", id, "; domain=.", window.location.host, "; path=" + window.location.pathname + ";"].join("");

}

// get value
var savedValue;
if (window.localStorage !== undefined) {
    savedValue = window.localStorage.getItem("li_id");
} else {
    savedValue = document.cookie.split(";")[0].split("=")[1];
}

alert(savedValue);
```

Note that `id` in snippet above is the value you want to store.

Answer (score 0):

What JimJimmy is said is correct. Are you using any server-side scripting ?

- if you are using just client-side script only way you can accomplish your task is 
  1) Cookies
  2) LocalStorage
  3) SessionStorage - just for that session

Answer (score 0):

You store data on a DOM node in jQuery using data, the variables are stored in on the node object. This is to accommodate complex objects and references as storing the data on the node element as an attribute will only accommodate string values.

```
$('#foo').data('foo', 'baz');

console.log( $('#foo').attr('data-foo') );
//outputs "bar" as the attribute was never changed

console.log( $('#foo').data('foo') );
//outputs "baz" as the value has been updated on the object
```